# unresolved external symbol in placement new operator

Tags: visual-studio-2010

After changing some files in project, following compilation error is coming. it seems it is unable to find library placement new operator.

> resiprocate.lib(Contents.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl >operator new(unsigned int,class resip::PoolBase *)" (??2@YAPAXIPAVPoolBase@resip@@@Z)
>   resiprocate.lib(ExistsOrDataParameter.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol >"void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int,class resip::PoolBase *)" (??>2@YAPAXIPAVPoolBase@resip@@@Z)
>   resiprocate.lib(StringCategory.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * >__cdecl operator new(unsigned int,class resip::PoolBase *)" (??>2@YAPAXIPAVPoolBase@resip@@@Z)
>   resiprocate.lib(Auth.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl >operator new(unsigned int,class resip::PoolBase *)" (??2@YAPAXIPAVPoolBase@resip@@@Z)
>   resiprocate.lib(UInt32Category.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * >__cdecl operator new(unsigned int,class resip::PoolBase *)" (??

Comment: Not Clear. Explain it then only you will get answer soon

Comment: i know these error is coming due to mismatch of definition of new operator but unable to find exact reason. i also #included<new> file but problem persist. I building the code of open source from http://www.resiprocate.org/Main_Page

Comment: probably you are missing some .lib file into your project.